# Count total number across post types

Tags: posts, count

I am using this code to count number of posts for one custom post type.

What's the best way to change this to sum up together 3 different custom post types?

```
function get_all_them_ven_posts(){
    $post_type = 'restaurants';
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type );

    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    return $published_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just get the count for each post type and sum them?

```
function get_all_them_ven_posts(){
  $count= 0;
  $post_types = [ 'postType1', 'postType2', 'postType3' ];
  foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $count_posts =  wp_count_posts( $post_type );
    $count = $count + $count_posts->publish;
  }
  return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious, so I [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php)d it with three post types and about 120 posts shared across them. Comparing three [`wp_count_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/) calls with one [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) call. If you make use of the `fields` parameter of the latter, with the value `ids`, then they are about the same speed, otherwise it is 30 times slower. The `get_posts()` method is possibly in the 95% rang in comparison, so it might be a little bit faster, but I didn't run nearly enough iterations to have a conclusive result. So I would say you can do it either way.

```
// use either
$p1c = wp_count_posts( 'post-type-1' )->publish;
$p2c = wp_count_posts( 'post-type-2' )->publish;
$p3c = wp_count_posts( 'post-type-3' )->publish;
$res = $p1c + $p2c + $p3c;
//alternatively
$pts = [ 'product', 'post', 'page' ];
$res = 0;
foreach ( $pts as $pt) {
    $res = $res + wp_count_posts( $pt )->publish;
}

// or use this
$res = count( get_posts( [ 
  'post_type' => [ 'product', 'post', 'page' ], 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'fields' => 'ids' 
] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Get total number of post in custom post type

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custompost', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$total = $loop->found_posts;
echo $total;
```

Comment: Use `'fields' => 'ids'` otherwise the performance is bad.